Unordered Set Classification Problem
In my setup I have one feature which is a sparse list representing categories. For example, let's say that we have M categories in the interval [0 .. M - 1]. My examples look like:

ex 1: [0, 2, 1]
ex 2: [3, 0]
ex 3: [1, 4, 5]

The order doesn't matter. So, let's suppose that we already know $f: s \rightarrow L$, where $s$ is the sequence and $L$ is the label, for example, lets consider just a toy function $f$ (in a real setting I don't know what $f$ looks like):
def toy_func(set):
    return int(
        0 in set
        and M // 2 in set
    )

So, I am trying to train a neural network, currently I have tried the following model:
class SimpleMultiCategoricalClassifier(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_embeddings, embedding_dim):
        super().__init__()

        self.embeddings = nn.EmbeddingBag(
                num_embeddings=num_embeddings,
                embedding_dim=embedding_dim, mode="mean")

        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embedding_dim, 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )
        
    def forward(self, input, offset):
        x = self.embeddings(input, offset)
        return self.net(x)

Basically I represent each "category" as an embedding, and then do pooling on the entire sequence to learn the function.
However my model is not learning anything. Is there a better way to frame the problem so I can learn the latent function?

Typical setup for this would be to
one hot encode
each unordered set, so we have $M$ boolean indicator variables.
And then we might train on cosine distance, to predict each label.
